# How do I tell which chapter I'm in?

Tags: death-stranding

The Map/Information screen shows the current objective, however is there a way to know the story chapter or overall game progression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of game chapters are named after characters and loading screens will feature this character. For example, "Chapter 2 - Amelie" has this loading screen:

> [image]

However, obviously you need to load/reload game to see loading screens.

---

As for overall game progression, here are some minor spoilers which help to establish where you are at:

1. Total number of chapters is

   > 15
2. Map progression:

   > Game map have 3 regions - Eastern, Central and Western regions. Western (Edge Node City) is very small, so as soon as you are close to connecting all nodes in Central region you are entering endgame.

Comment: I don't believe this warrants adding another answer, so I'll point out that each chapter has a secret trophy and the player could refer to those as well to determine their current chapter...provided that the player hasn't already finished the game.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you load the game or complete an objective, the game tells you what the current story mission is. In small letters above that, it tells you what the current chapter is.